# Putting if else in nginx Vhost configuration with Puppet Nginx jfryman module

Tags: if-statement, nginx, url-rewriting, puppet, conditional-statements

I want to automate the nginx vhost configuration for a website which have some if conditional statements. I was trying to do it with the [jfryman-nginx](https://github.com/jfryman/puppet-nginx) puppet forge module but I am not able to configure the file. The configuration I want is given below:

```
 server {
  listen   8080;

  server_name abcqwe.com;

  root /data/vvv/abcqwe.com;
  index index.php index.html index.htm;

  access_log /data/vvv/abcqwe.com/logs/access.log;
  error_log  /data/vvv/abcqwe.com/logs/error.log;

  location / {
    # First attempt to serve request as file, then
    # as directory, then fall back to index.html
    #try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;

    if (!-f $request_filename){
      set $rule_0 1$rule_0;
    }

    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
  }
```

So how do i put this if condition inside my vhost configuration:

```
 if (!-f $request_filename){
       set $rule_4 1$rule_4;
     }
```

Is it possible to do it though? I have tried with `location_cfg_prepend` but that didn't help..

Comment: I' not clear what you are asking, but try to read "If is Evil" article.

Comment: I have the same problem and am still looking for a solution. The problem seems to be with location_cfg_prepend adding a ; after the closing if } in the generated config file. nginx does not seem to like that. location_cfg_append does the same thing.

Comment: @zuniga I posted an answer. There's a fix in the latest source on github, but it's not in puppet forge.

Comment: Thanks @GuyHughes I will give the latest version a try but that is not a good enough solution for me in production and will have to wait till  the fix is released

Comment: @zuniga, the github `master` branch should be production quality. The easy option is to take the v0.0.9 module as in puppet forge, and edit the `.erb` templates to remove the semicolon where appropriate. You could use [a patch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Patch_(Unix)) to apply the changes across your production machines.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem with v0.0.9 of jfryman-nginx.

[In the latest source templates on github](https://github.com/jfryman/puppet-nginx/blob/master/templates/vhost/vhost_location_directory.erb), it looks like the `;` is not supposed to be added if you use `location_custom_cfg_{pre,ap}pend`.

But [in v0.0.9, the latest bundled puppet forge release](https://github.com/jfryman/puppet-nginx/blob/v0.0.9/templates/vhost/vhost_location_directory.erb), the template adds the `;` after even if the line only has a `}` causing `nginx` to fail.

### Solutions:

1. Use the `location_**custom**_cfg_{pre,ap}pend` options
2. Either A or B:

   A. Edit out the `;` in the templates

   B. Pull the latest version of the source from github:

sudo rm -rf /etc/puppet/modules/nginx && cd /etc/puppet/modules && sudo git clone https://github.com/jfryman/puppet-nginx nginx

### Example

```
  nginx::resource::location { 'sub.dom.com_root':
    ensure                                                                       => present,
    vhost                                                                        => 'sub.dom.com',
    location                                                                     => '~ \.php$',
    fastcgi                                                                      => 'unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock',                                                                                                                                                              
    www_root                                                                     => '/var/www/sub.dom.com',
    location_custom_cfg_append                                                   => {
      'if (-f $request_filename)'                                                => '{ break; }',
      'if (-d $request_filename)'                                              => '{ break; }',
      'if ($request_filename !~ (js|css|jpg|png|gif|robots\.txt|index\.php.*) )' => '{ rewrite ^/(.*) /index.php?$1 last; }',
    },
  }
```

Comment: i solved it by adding # as the last char and forcing the extra ; to become a comment:  'if (-f $request_filename)' => '{ break; }#'

Answer (score 0):

You can now use the `raw_prepend` and `raw_append` parameters for this.

See the [location.pp](https://github.com/jfryman/puppet-nginx/blob/master/manifests/resource/location.pp) page for more detail.

Answer (score -1):

Please try to use `LuaModule` in nginx,`Lua` Module having lot of configuration.

in `Lua` syntax very simple to use.

Please read [this](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpLuaModule)